# Windows Forms dataGridView - how to set rows enable on click event

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I'm making a form using `DataGridView`but I've unchecked all `Enables` for the columns and the rows and I've added a button `Add New` whose idea is to add a new row when is clicked. But I can't figure out the way to do this.

Comment: How are you passing the data to the dataGridView - by using DataTable or some other way?

Comment: For now it's just dummy data for presenting the user interface. For is enough just to implement the functionality of adding a new row on button click. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easyest way is to create a DataTable with the structure you need. Add a DataSet to your project (Project -> Add new item -> DataSet (inside the data section)). In there you can create a DataTable with the structure you need (right click -> Add -> DataTable). Then you can bind the following code to the button you use:
`MyDataSet dsMyDataSet = new MyDataSet()
 dsMyDataSet.MyDataTable[0] = value; // repeat this line for each column, or place it into a loop to do it for you`
And then you display your data with this line:

 `dataGridView1.DataSource = dsMyDataSet.MyDataTable;`

This should solve your problem.